# How can i modify googlechart DataView annotation from arrayToDataTable that get data from json encode?

Tags: javascript, php, json, annotations, google-visualization

my PHP :

```
$chart = array(
array('axisX'=>'0','value'=>$temp_value[0]),
array('axisX'=>'1','value'=>$temp_value[1]),
array('axisX'=>'2','value'=>$temp_value[2]),
array('axisX'=>'3','value'=>$temp_value[3]),
array('axisX'=>'4','value'=>$temp_value[4]),
array('axisX'=>'5','value'=>$temp_value[5]),
array('axisX'=>'6','value'=>$temp_value[6]),
array('axisX'=>'7','value'=>$temp_value[7]),
array('axisX'=>'8','value'=>$temp_value[8]),
array('axisX'=>'9','value'=>$temp_value[9]));

function convertDataToChartForm($chart)
{
    $newData = array();
    $firstLine = true;

    foreach ($chart as $dataRow)
    {
        if ($firstLine)
        {
            $newData[] = array_keys($dataRow);
            $firstLine = false;
        }

        $newData[] = array_values($dataRow);
    }

    return $newData;
}
```

Thisi is my script :

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<?php echo json_encode(convertDataToChartForm($chart));?>);

var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
      view.setColumns([0, 1,
                       { calc: "stringify",
                         sourceColumn: 1,
                         type: "string",
                         role: "annotation" }]);
```

what i want to try to achieve is i want to add "x" after the annotation? For example the annotation output is 9 and i want to it become "9x".

Answer (score 0):

rather than using the built in `"stringify"` function,
you can use your own custom function.

the calc function will receive two arguments,
the data table, and the row index

```
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns([0, 1, {
  calc: function (dt, row) {
    return dt.getFormattedValue(row, 1) + 'x';
  },
  type: "string",
  role: "annotation"
}]);
```